# Modeling the dissolution of an oil droplet with detergent

Tags: fluid-dynamics, mathematical-physics, physical-chemistry

How to model the dissolution of an oil droplet on the surface of water when a detergent is (gradually) added to the water?

I believe this includes an interplay of coalescence keeping the droplet together and dissolution tearing it apart. Adding the detergent then changes the system so that the dissolution becomes stronger.

So far I tried a partial differential equation approach with the [Cahn–Hilliard equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cahn%E2%80%93Hilliard_equation). However this model seems not to account for the coalescence, so that the droplet is always dissolved regardless of the parameters.

[image: oil droplet]

Comment: I believe adding the detergent pushes the equilibrium $\mathrm{droplets}\leftrightarrow \mathrm{"solution"}$ to the right completely. Coalescense is therefore negligible. I might formulate an answer along those lines, later.

Comment: look at Chapter 19 of Intermolecular and Surface Forces, Jacob N. Israelachvili, in particular sections [19.2, 19.7).

Comment: Nice book! At the first glimpse it seems that one would need to model the system starting from a molecular level and with some more details on which oil and detergent is used etc..

Comment: It is a nice book indeed. Have also a look at Chapter 12 of Physics and Chemistry of Interfaces, Hans-Jürgen Butt, Karlheinz Graf, Michael Kappl

Answer (score 0):

The term *dissolution* is a little misleading when we're dealing with a immiscible system of oil and water. As the oil is wholly insoluble in water, at best and upon intense agitation (shaking e.g.) an *unstable* [emulsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulsion) (a *two phase system*) of oil in water will form. This process will over time and usually quite quickly be reversed through coalescense of the oil.

However, adding a suitable detergent changes the nature of the formed emulsion strongly. Although still a two phase system, the oil droplets are present in the form of highly stabilised [micelles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micelle#Solvation). Depending on the 'quality' of the detergent, such emulsions can be indefinitely stable, without any tendency toward re-coalescense ('separating out' of the oil).

By **analogy** with a chemical *equilibrium reaction* we could write:

$$\mathrm{liquid_{.}oil}\leftrightarrow \mathrm{oil_{.}micelles}$$

Pushing the anlogy a little further we could introduce an equilibrium constant $K$:

$$K=\frac{[\mathrm{oil_{.}micelles}]}{[\mathrm{liquid_{.}oil}]}$$

The bracketed terms indicate quantities.

Using a 'good quality' detergent we can then say that:

$$K\gg 1$$

This means that in modelling the solvation of the oil, re-coalescense can be neglected and the process considered as a one way process.

Comment: Ok already a bit of detergent is enough to transform the oil droplet to micelles.
But what happens when we add detergent in even lower quantity?
I can see three possibilities:
1. Some micelles form and the majority of the drop stay intact, so that the droplet becomes smaller when more detergent is added.
2. The droplet splits into two parts, then three etc until micelles are formed.
3. The droplet forms sort of "tentacles" which increase its surface with the water while not separating the oil droplet entirely.
Do I miss sth, or do they occur together maybe depending on the circumstances?